# How to read Binary file on PYTHON from unknown encoding?

Tags: python, encoding, binary

I have a problem when I try to read a binary file in python.

I can read this binary file easily with MATLAB:

```
file_id = fopen("file.bin", "r");
file = fread(file_id);
fclose(file_id);
dataA = typecast (uint8(file),"uint16");
data = double(dataA);
```

But I now have to read it with **python**, I tried several methods :

```
import numpy as np
import base64
file_id = open("file.bin", "rb");
file = file_id.read();
```

Method 1:

```
A = base64.b64decode(file);
file = np.uint16(A);
```

Method 2:

```
A = file.decode(encoding='utf-16', errors='ignore');
```

Method 3:

```
A = bytes(file).decode(encoding='utf-16', errors='strict')
```

Method 4:

```
with codecs.open('file.bin', 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='strict') as fdata:
A = codecs.lookup(fdata);
```

...

```
file_id.close;
```

But the format is still not good I can't read the file. I should get an integer sequence but I get only special characters, you have an idea?

Comment: UTF is for encoding text, you don't want that for this task. Since you have Numpy, you should be able to read the data correctly using [numpy.fromfile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html). You could also do it in plain Python with the help of the `struct` module. It would help potential answerers if you could post a few lines of a hexdump of a typical file along with the numbers that it's supposed to contain.

Comment: `A = np.fromfile(file_id, 'uint16');` seems to work perfectly! This method was not in the helper of numpy :( 
I have a second binary file but written in utf-8 encoding text (working with decode method) that's why I was confused, I was not able to know the format of the binary file. Thanks a lot, you save my day!